# Proof for new deterministic primality test possible?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Conjecture:

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n$ odd.
>
> Then the number $N=2^2 + n^2$ is prime, if and only if $N$ divides $2^{(N-1)/2} + 1$.

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't find counterexamples up to n=10^8, might be wrong.

Comment: the "only if" part is [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234348/can-b41-be-a-pseudoprime-to-base-2-except-for-fermat-numbers

Comment: No counterexamples for $n$ below $2^{32}$. In fact, below $2^{64}$ there is only one pseudoprime $N$ of the form $n^2+4$ (for $n=22047$), but it does not divive $2^{(N-1)/2}+1$.

Comment: Nice question. Even if true, it wouldn't give a deterministic primality test as stated, since it can't be applied to arbitrary candidates for primality. I'd call it a prime distinguisher.

Comment: @kodlu: 1.) I did not say, this test is a general primality test. As anyone can read, it is a primality test for numbers of the form $2^2+n^2$.  2.) If conjecture holds, it is definitely a deterministic test. 3.) If we take for $n$ numbers of the form $n=2^k+1$, this primality test has - with fast modular exponentiation - nearly the same time complexity as Lucas-Lehmer test. So this test is also for huge numbers usable.

Comment: @Guest: Did you have a special reason for choosing $n^2+4$, rather than any other polynomial whose values are all congruent to 3 or 5 mod 8?

Comment: @SJR: There is no special reason. I have choosen it, because it is simple.

Comment: Tested all $n$ below $10^{11}$, no counterexamples found.